# Safely using remote HTML

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, escaping, firefox-addon-sdk, html-sanitizing

I have been asked to pass some html which is being sent from my server to my Firefox add-on through a function called `parseHTML` by a Mozilla add-on reviewer. The method in question is documented in [this XUL school tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_School/DOM_Building_and_HTML_Insertion#Safely_Using_Remote_HTML).

In my content script however, `typeof parseHTML == "undefined"`. I believe this is because my add-on is built using the add-on SDK, not XUL.

It is correct that add-ons built with the SDK do not have access to this method? Is there an equivalent method in the SDK?

Comment: Of course this function isn't defined - its source code is quoted in the tutorial you link to. What you really need is [nsIParserUtils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIParserUtils), something that your add-on code (not the content script) can access. So, does that HTML code go through your add-on code? Note that while XUL school tutorial is old - the particular document you linked to is pretty new and very much up to date.

Comment: No, it's built from a JS template in the content script. It sounds like I'd have to compile a template at runtime in the content script, emit a message to the add-on code, passing along the html string. Sanitize the html string then pass it back to the content script for rendering? Sounds like fun :-)

Comment: Or maybe change the templating mechanism (no idea what you are using there) so that it doesn't deal with raw HTML code? If you can use `.textContent` to fill in dynamic data then it will be safe without any sanitizing.

Comment: I already am sanitizing everything using [Underscore's escape function](http://underscorejs.org/#escape). Apparently that's not enough.

Comment: The disadvantage of using that function is that you can easily forget escaping in some place, something that would result in a security vulnerability. Maybe that's what the reviewer meant - better to use a more robust approach. Then again, there is always the possibility that the reviewer simply missed that aspect of your code.

Comment: Yeah. That's true. I've looked over the code about ten times now and I'm positive that there is no security vulnerability. In this particular piece of code it might look like there is a vulnerability if you just glance at it but any potential vulnerability is actually mitigated deeper up the render stack. It's just very hard to get any discourse going during the review process so I can't explain. Anyway, at this point I've resigned myself to just removing the offending code.

Comment: @WladimirPalant Do you want to just stick that top comment in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this function is undefined - it isn't some globally defined helper but rather something you have to define in your code (as shown in the code example). It uses the [`nsIParserUtils` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIParserUtils) that you would need to have access to. In an SDK-based extension you would use [chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.11/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html) for that:

```js
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var parser = Cc["@mozilla.org/parserutils;1"].getService(Ci.nsIParserUtils);
var sanitized = parser.sanitize(html, parser.SanitizerAllowStyle);
```

If you are in a content script then you cannot use that of course - you would need to send the HTML code to the add-on, sanitize it there and send it back to the content script. While this is an option, you might want to consider other possibilities like not using `innerHTML` in the first place (if all you need is setting some text on an element then `textContent` is a safe alternative).

Side-note: While XUL Tutorial is rather old, this particular page has only been imported into MDN a year ago - and updated regularly since that according to history. So it is current, just not meant explicitly for the Add-on SDK (like most MDN articles actually).